# How to easily add columns to a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can add any number and types of columns into a temp table without the need to define them first:

```
select into #temp from table;
```

But if I want to add columns to this temp table later on in my script, the only way I know how is to:

```
alter #temp add column int;
insert into #table (column) select column from table;
```

This is a bit cumbersome if I want to add multiple columns. Is there a way to add column to a temp table without defining them first?

Comment: drop the temp table each time you want to add a column and use `select..into..from..` construct, because you don't want to define them first

Comment: without defining it you can not alter it. temp table are designed when they are used. So you can update but can not alter.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `insert` is appropriate after adding a column.  `Update` seems more like the operation you would want.

One option is to create a new temporary table:

```
select t.*, 'value' as col
into #temp1
from #temp t;
```

However, for an existing table, there is no way to add a column and populate it at the same time -- except for providing a default value.

You can, however, add multiple columns at the *same* time:

```
alter #temp add col1 int, col2 int, col3 int;

update #temp t
    set col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is almost certain you know how many columns you finally need. You can create the extra columns (not present in your table/query result) with dummy constant values when creating your #temp table.

e.g.

```
select *, '' as AdditionalStringColumn into #temp from table1;

select *, 0 as AdditionalIntegerColumn into #temp from table1;

select *, 0.0 as AdditionalDecimalColumn into #temp from table1;
```

This way you don't need to get into the mess of dealing with `alter table` etc., and will have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i like to use this type of adding column and update after:

```
select *
into #tmp
            from openquery(PARADOX_SRV_TEST, 'select * from D:\WinMent\DATA\TESTP\Npart.DB ') p


            ALTER TABLE #tmp ADD District nvarchar(10), SimbolClasa nvarchar(100)

            Update t 
            set t.District = (Select District from Cities c where c.Id = t.Localit)
            from #tmp t

            Update t 
            set t.SimbolClasa = (Select ISNULL(Simbol,'ND') as Simbol from CustomersCategory c where c.Cod = t.Clasa)
            from #tmp t

            select *,  ISNULL(c.Simbol,'Nedefinit') as Simbol from #tmp t 
            LEFT JOIN CustomersCategory c on c.Cod = t.Clasa
```

If i use this type of adding:

```
select *, '' as AdditionalStringColumn into #temp from table1;
```

sometimes i recive this type of error:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 8
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```